# iOS: Setting the rootViewController doesn't remove the old presented view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have in my objective-c application a loginViewController from where I display the homeViewController after the user logged in successfully. This is how I display the home:

```
-(void) displayHome {
UIViewController * home = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];
    _window.rootViewController = publicHome;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

The `displayHome` function is in the `AppDelegate`. After that, in the homeViewController i present some view controllers using

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:false completion:nil];
```

Sometimes I have to redirect the user to the loginViewController so I call this VC the same as I do for the home (by setting the rootViewController) in order to remove all the other views. But when I use the 3d debugger I see that the presented views are there. 
Why when I set the `rootViewController` with the `loginViewController`, the presented views are not removed even if there are attached to the `homeViewController` that is as the `rootViewController`?

**Edit**

An example:

Suppose that from the `homeViewController`(that is the `rootViewController`) I go to the `viewController1` (`viewController1` is presented). Now when I press a button in the `viewController1` I have to return to the `loginViewController`. In the button action, this is what I do:

I call

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];
```

and `[appDelegate displayLogin];`

```
//AppDelegate
-(void) displayLogin {
UIViewController * login = [self.mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeViewController"];
    _window.rootViewController = publicHome;
    [_window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

When I debug, I find that the `viewController1` is still here. It under the login. Why is the `viewController1` here even if I set the `rootViewController`?

Comment: your question is not clear. Presented view controllers are always stay on top on root view controller until u dismiss the presented controller.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri check my edit please

Comment: try calling [appDelegate displayLogin] in the completion block of dismissViewControllerAnimated.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri I tried it but the viewController1 is still here

Comment: Two thing 1. Just check if it is dismissing at first place or not don't call displayLogin 2. Try adding delay in displayLogin by using dispatch inside dismiss completion block.

Comment: I had faced same issue. You can take help from ans provided to my question I asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33564261/logout-from-ios-app).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should first check whether the method `-dealloc` has been executed in you UIViewControllers. Try add this code in `viewController1`:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"ViewController %@ dealloc", NSStringFromClass([self class]));
}
```

If this method hasn't been invoked, then check whether there is still any strong reference pointing to `viewController1` after you called `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:nil];`

Answer (score -1):

This usually happens due to the retaincount, check your implementation and make sure there is no completion block or something which is not letting dealloc get called. Once your dealloc gets called all views will get removed

Comment: can you explain more please? An can you also check my edit?